TortoiseGit not pulling public submodules: asks for credentials
Using TortoiseGit on Win10, when I git pull one of my private repository that contains submodules, they remain empty. If I do [Update submodules] and specify [Recursive] I get a popup with "No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)"
I don't understand why since the submodule is public. Doing a simple git clone of the repo of the module without providing credentials works fine, so why does it want credentials when doing it as a submodule ?
Here's the complete log:
git.exe submodule update --progress --init --recursive
Cloning into 'C:/Users/dargaud/Devel/genepi3/trunk/DimGpio/Modules/PanelManagement'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@gitlab.com:dargaud/PanelManagement.git' into submodule path 'C:/Users/dargaud/Devel/genepi3/trunk/DimGpio/Modules/PanelManagement' failed
Failed to clone 'trunk/DimGpio/Modules/PanelManagement'. Retry scheduled
Cloning into 'C:/Users/dargaud/Devel/genepi3/trunk/DimGpio/Modules/PanelManagement'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.
fatal: clone of 'git@gitlab.com:dargaud/PanelManagement.git' into submodule path 'C:/Users/dargaud/Devel/genepi3/trunk/DimGpio/Modules/PanelManagement' failed
Failed to clone 'trunk/DimGpio/Modules/PanelManagement' a second time, aborting

git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (53172 ms @ 2024-08-21 16:11:20)

